# Multithreading with PySide : is my structure viable?

Tags: python, multithreading, qt, pyqt, pyside

I'm running into a very strange error while using `QThread` in PySide. As I run my code, when I click on the button that is supposed to launch the thread and send `Signal`, I get :

```
AttributeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object has no attribute 'displayText'
```

at line :

```
self.displayMessage.connect(self.window.displayText)
```

NB : `displayText` is a method that I defined in my `MainWindow(QWidget)` class, while `displayMessage` is the signal to be emitted.

This error seems, according to the Internet, to occur in various situations, and I couldn't find one that suits my case yet. Therefore I have 2 questions :

- Have you guys ever met this error before in a similar situation, and could you (if yes) give me some tips ?
- Am I doing it right ? I can't post my code directly down here, so I created a *short verifiable example* in which I used the same process. Unfortunately, it seems to work perfectly. Please tell me if at least my construction is correct.

Thank you very much.

---

**EDIT :** I eventually figured out that I have forgotten a `self` somewhere in my big code, but the actual error was hidden to me behind this one that I didn't know. I'm still interested in whether or not this code is reliable, and am fully open to suggestions of improvement.

---

**Without thread**

When you click *"GO !"* and try to move the window, you can see that it freezes for a second.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- encoding : utf-8 -*-
import sys
import time
from PySide.QtCore import *
from PySide.QtGui import *

class MainWindow(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, qt_app):
        QWidget.__init__(self)
        worker = Worker(self)
        self.qt_app = qt_app
        self.setGeometry(100, 100, 220, 40)
        self.infoPanel = QTextEdit(self)
        self.infoPanel.setReadOnly(True)
        self.goButton = QPushButton('GO !', self)
        self.goButton.clicked.connect(lambda: worker.displayOnWindow())
        self.layout = QVBoxLayout()
        self.layout.addWidget(self.infoPanel)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.goButton)
        self.setLayout(self.layout)
    def launch(self):
        self.show()
        self.qt_app.exec_()

class Worker():
    def __init__(self, window):
        self.counter = 0
        self.window = window
    def displayOnWindow(self):
        time.sleep(1)
        self.window.infoPanel.append(str(self.counter))
        self.counter += 1

if __name__=='__main__':
    qt_app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    mw = MainWindow(qt_app)
    mw.launch()
```

**With thread**

Now you can move the window without trouble, since the sleeping thread is not the one that displays the window. I've written a sub-class for my thread because in the original code there are some functions that will be called by several buttons.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- encoding : utf-8 -*-
import sys
import time
from PySide.QtCore import *
from PySide.QtGui import *

class MainWindow(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, qt_app):
        QWidget.__init__(self)
        worker = SubWorker(self)
        self.qt_app = qt_app
        self.setGeometry(100, 100, 220, 40)
        self.infoPanel = QTextEdit(self)
        self.infoPanel.setReadOnly(True)
        self.goButton = QPushButton('GO !', self)
        self.goButton.clicked.connect(lambda: worker.start())
        self.layout = QVBoxLayout()
        self.layout.addWidget(self.infoPanel)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.goButton)
        self.setLayout(self.layout)
    def launch(self):
        self.show()
        self.qt_app.exec_()
    @Slot(int)
    def displayOnWindow(self, i):
        self.infoPanel.append(str(i))

class Worker(QThread):
    displayMessage = Signal(int)
    def __init__(self, window):
        QThread.__init__(self)
        self.counter = 0
        self.window = window
        self.displayMessage.connect(self.window.displayOnWindow)
    def run(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return QThread.run(self, *args, **kwargs)

class SubWorker(Worker):
    def __init__(self, window):
        Worker.__init__(self, window)
    def run(self):
        time.sleep(1)
        self.displayMessage.emit(self.counter)
        self.counter += 1

if __name__=='__main__':
    qt_app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    mw = MainWindow(qt_app)
    mw.launch()
```

Comment: Where does `SubWorker` fit into this.  It would be good if you included the creation and connection code in your 2nd example.  There's also no reference to `displayText` in any of the code you presented, so I'm guessing there's some other pertinent code you haven't given.

Comment: Ok I figured out why it didn't work : I had forgotten a `self` somewhere in my big code. I will edit the question. Anyway, I'm still interested in whether or not the code is right

Comment: @BrendanAbel I will edit so that it is more clear :)

Comment: @BrendanAbel It's edited. For `displayText`, it's the function I use in the original code, but it does pretty much what `displayOnWindow` does here.

Comment: It would make more sense for you to connect the signal in the main thread so that you don't have to pass the window to the `QThread`.  GUI objects can't be modified outside the main thread, so it doesn't make sense for them to store references to it.

Comment: Isn't this already what I've done ? I don't understand how to "connect the signal in the main thread". What do you suggest ?

Comment: No, you're passing the `window` to the `QThread`, then making the connection inside the `QThread`.  Also, what is your question now?  Is your code working?

Comment: @BrendanAbel Yes it does work fine, I just wanted to know if this were "pythonic" as they say, and efficient as well.